# Where to find meteor accounts-google typings?

Tags: angular-meteor

What is the equivalent of `@types/meteor-accounts-phone` (`mys:accounts-phone`) when using `accounts-google` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that "@types/meteor" is the correct answer, since the the accounts-google package uses the default meteor api and "@types/meteor" already includes support for these signatures.